# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sponsorship_type' cannot be null

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, static, dropdown

When the **User** tries to add/store an **sponsor** along with **sponsorship type** in his CMS, I get this error **SQLSTATE[23000]**. Im wondering what could be the reason for this error. The row wasnt previously set to null, and I it shouldnt be because the sponsor must have a certain **sponsorship type**.

This is my view:

```
<div class="panel-body">

    <div class="panel-body list-group list-group-contacts">
    @foreach($event->sponsors as $sponsor)
            {{ Form::open(array( 'route' => array( 'remove.sponsor.from.conference' , $event->id ) , 'method'     => 'DELETE' )) }}
            {{ Form::hidden('sponsor' , $sponsor->id) }}

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <span class="contacts-title">{{ $sponsor->name }}</span> <br>
            <span class="contacts-title">{{ \Events\Models\Sponsor::$_SPONSORSHIP_TYPES[$sponsor->pivot->sponsorship_type][0] }}</span>
            <div class="list-group-controls">
                {{ Form::submit('X' , array( 'class'    => 'btn btn-primary btn-rounded' )) }}
            </div>
        </a>
        <br/>

        {{ Form::close() }}

    @endforeach
    </div>

    <h2>Add Sponsor</h2>

        {{ Form::open(array( 'route' => array('add.sponsor.to.conference' , $event->id) , 'method' => 'POST')) }}
            <select name="sponsor" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Choose sponsor</option>

            @foreach($sponsors as $sponsor)

                <option value="{{$sponsor->id}}">{{ $sponsor->name }}</option>

            @endforeach
            </select>
            <br>
            <select name="sponsorship_types"  class="form-control">
                <option value="">Choose sponsorship type</option>
                @foreach(\Events\Models\Sponsor::$_SPONSORSHIP_TYPES as $key => $value)

                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value[0] }}</option>

                @endforeach
            </select>
            <br>
```

Controller function:

```
public function addSponsorToConference($event_id)
    {
        if (Input::get('sponsor') != "" && is_numeric(Input::get('sponsor')) )
        {
            $sponsor = Sponsor::find(Input::get('sponsor'));
            $conference = Event::find($event_id);
            $conference->sponsors()->save($sponsor, array('sponsorship_type' => Input::get('sponsorship_type')));
        }
        return Redirect::back();
    }


    public function removeSponsorFromConference($event_id)
    {
        $conference = Event::find($event_id);
        $conference->sponsors()->detach(Input::get('sponsor'));
        return Redirect::back();
    }
```

Model:

```
class Sponsor extends BaseModel {


    public static $_SPONSORSHIP_TYPES = array(
        1 => ['Platinum sponsors', 400, 150],
        2 => ['Gold sponsors', 300, 100],
        3 => ['Silver sponsors', 200, 80],
        4 => ['Bronze sponsors', 150, 70],
        5 => ['Media partner', 60, 60],
    );

    protected $table = 'sponsors';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'logo', 'link', 'description'];

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\Events\Models\Conference');
    }

}
```

Event Model:

```
class Event extends BaseModel {

    protected $table = 'events';

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'description', 'ticket_limit', 'location', 'gmap_location'];

 public function sponsors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\Events\Models\Sponsor')->withPivot("sponsorship_type");
    }

    public function getSponsorsForShow()
    {
        $return = array();
        foreach(Sponsor::$_SPONSORSHIP_TYPES as $key => $value){
            $sponsors = $this->sponsors()->where("sponsorship_type", "=", $key)->get();
            if(count($sponsors)) $return[] = array("height" => $value[2], "width" => $value[1], "sponsors" => $sponsors, "sponsorship_title"=>$value[0]);
        }

        return $return;
    }

}
```

Comment: `$conference->sponsors()->save()` looks to cause the error. How is this relationship defined in `conference` model ?

Comment: I think also! It used to work quite good.

Comment: I have added Conference model below!

Comment: Actually we need this Event model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple fix.

```
Input::get('sponsorship_type')
```

This returns null which your database doesn't like.  The only way this should return null is if there was no field named `sponsorship_type`.

So looking at your HTML, you have `<select name="sponsorship_types"  class="form-control">`

I think you need to change the `name` of this element to `sponsorship_type`.

Comment: The s was the fix! Thanks! Good catch.